# ListView может в 2 колонки выводиться?

Tags: java, android

Нужно вывести `ListView` в две колонки т.е. 2 значения из списка в одну строку типа `GridLayout` и т.п.
В интернете не нашёл примеров для `ListView`, все примеры только с использованием `RecyclerView`

Пример списка в 2 колонки:
[image: Пример]

Comment: Хоть вам и дали ответ на ваш вопрос, я крайне рекомендую пересесть на RecyclerView. Он и с любым числом столбцов может работать, и реализация у него более адекватная с точки зрения производительности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не может.

Но можно в нём (в качестве элемента (пункта)) создать вьюшку (View) с 2-мя вьюшками внутри и подставлять в них то что нужно. Получится тот же результат, в две колонки.

**UPD:** Вот пример итема:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- тут контент для левой колонки -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- тут контент для правой колонки -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Пример не скините как 2 view сделать или как в поиск правильно забить чтобы найти ? А то с recyclerview пока сложности

Comment: Добавил пример.